# Subtraction on numpy array not working

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have  a `4D numpy array`. I am trying to normalize it's value for that I need to subtract some value from it but the operation is adding the values.

Please help

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_train[0][0][0])
print(X_train[0][0][0]-128)
```

It's output is:

```
(34799, 32, 32, 3)

[28 25 24]

[156 153 152]
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
[-100,-103,-102]
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
I am new to `numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it's a 4-dimensional array is not the point here.

I **guess** that your problem is with the [data type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) of that numpy array. For example, if it's `numpy.uint8` (unsigned byte, i.e. allowing only values in [0,255]) then subtracting 128 from 28 will give you 156... :)

Try: `print (X_train.dtype)` to see the data type associated with your numpy array.

If that's the case, then consider converting it to some other dtype, e.g. `X_train = X_train.astype(numpy.int16)`, or simply to `numpy.int8`, depending on your expectations from your data.